# Joining a table through another join table using withRelated

Tags: bookshelf.js

I have 3 tables:

`Order: id`

`Item: id`

`OrderItems: order_id, item_id`

I want to be able to fetch a particular Order and get all the Items related to that Order, without the clutter introduced by doing `Order.where(...).fetch({withRelated: ['orderItem.item'])`.

Ideally I'd like to do `Order.where(...).fetch({withRelated: ['items'])` and the `items` relationship knows to go through the `OrderItems` table to get the information.

I have tried the relationship

```
items() {
     return this.hasMany('Item').through('OrderItem')
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work as I'd expected.

Is this possible using Bookshelf's API without writing a manual join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship you tried:

```
items() {
  return this.hasMany('Item').through('OrderItem')
}
```

Means to Bookshelf:

> Item(id, OrderItem_id) -> OrderItem(id, Order_id) -> Order(id)

Or a 1:n:m relationship.

But your database says:

> Item(id) <- OrderItem(Item_id, Order_id) -> Order(id)

This kind of relationship on Bookshelf maps better as [`belongsToMany()`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-belongsToMany):

```
bookshelf.plugin('registry')  // to ease the cyclic mapping

const Item = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'item',
  orders: function() {
    this.belongsToMany('Order', 'OrderItem')
  },
})
bookshelf.model('Item', Item)

const Order = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'order',
  items: function() {
    //return this.hasMany('Item').through('OrderItem')
    return this.belongsToMany('Item', 'OrderItem')
  },
})
bookshelf.model('Order', Order)
```

*Note that until you start placing useful data on the intermediate table you don't need to create a model for it.*

With that a `Order.where(...).fetch({withRelated: 'items'}).then(...)` query should *work as expected*.

Comment: Thank you so much @flaviodesousa. That seems to work. The only problem is, I'm getting `relation "OrderItem" does not exist`. I have defined it as a model using the registry model. For me the only way to get this working is to type the table name instead. Ideally I'd like to keep this in one place (the `OrderItem` model). Any idea how to get that working like your example?

Comment: Unfortunately the current version of bookshelf uses a table, instead of a model, to do the n:m mapping. But as I mentioned on the last Note you can still have a model for the intermediate table, for the case you have data on it (like quantity, price on the order-item case). How/where are you getting this `relation "OrderItem" does not exist` error?

Comment: I was initially assuming that as well as taking a table name it could take a Model, so for that reason I was passing my intermediate model to it. Swapping this out for the table name itself worked fine. Thank you for all your help.